# Application failed codesign verification

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store

I'm getting the following error when trying to submit my app to the app store. I went through the initial provisioning process and am able to run the app on my phone so not sure what's wrong.

```
Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate.
```

**EDIT:** I tried downloading and installing a Distribution profile, but I'm still getting the error. Is there some way I need to link this new profile to my app in XCode? Thanks!

**EDIT 2:** I've now gotten a distribution provisioning profile from Apple and tried compiling with this. Getting the error "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."

Comment: Tried restarting Xcode / your iPhone / your computer yet?

Comment: Yeah tried all that. Even created a new app.

Comment: Are you trying to install a Distribution build on your device?  That won't work.  Builds using App Store Distribution profiles are only for submission to the App store (when building using the released non-beta SDK).

Answer (score 14):

Verify the following:

- When creating the distibution profile, make sure that **Distribution Method is "App Store"**.
- In project settings, go to Build tab and make sure **Code Signing Identity** is the distribution profile you created for the App Store
- In Target settings (double-click on Target in your project), go to Build tab and make sure **Code Signing Identity** is the distribution profile you created for the App Store

It's recommended that you have a configuration in your project settings for AdHoc and App Store builds. I've found it makes life easier when it comes time to deploy.

Comment: This is the right answer, but to put a finer point on it... when building for distribution, make sure you use the "iPhone Distribution" setting in the project settings for the provisioning profile, which is different from the "iPhone Development" one.  Thus, having two separate configurations is recommended.  (I generally have "Simulator", "Device", "AdHoc", and "Deployment".)

Answer (score 3):

For the Xcode build warning or Archive Validation error **"Application failed codesign verification"**, see Apple's complete list of potential causes for this problem at "[How do I resolve the error: Application failed codesign verification?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG32)".

For the error **"A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found"**, typically this error occurs while attempting to run your app on device thru Xcode yet you mentioned that you're uploading the app to the store? Ensure that you're following the recommended steps for uploading your iOS app to the store using 
"[Steps to submit your app to the App Store](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG13)".

For others receiving the error **"A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found"** check that you're following Apple's recommended steps for running on device thru Xcode at "[Steps to run your app on device thru Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG20)".

Answer (score 1):

You can either double click a .mobileprovision file, or manually copy it to ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles. Then it will show up inside the provisioning popup in your Target settings.

Comment: where do I find the .mobileprovision file?

Comment: Ok, got a mobileprovision file from Apple. Now when I try to compile I get: "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found." and the build fails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Set the provisioning profile for both Project and Active Target.

Click Project -> Edit Project Settings change the code signing entity
Click Project ->Edit Active Target and change the same code signing entity here as well.

You should be good to go.!

Comment: No need to do it on target, target inherits the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you provisioning profile is a distribution profile for app store and not a development/ad-hoc one??

Comment: I just downloaded and installed a Distribution profile, but I'm still getting the error. Is there some way I need to link this new profile to my app in XCode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be caused if you incorrectly configured your application's "entitlements". A good place to check is for a warning in Xcode's Log Navigator (last page in left tab) and ensure that there is a green tick next to both the CodeSign and Validate steps in the build log when you Archive your project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is what I did to get it to work:

It turned out my Entitlements file was misformed.

Through much trial and error I have figured out the issue.  For others' sanity, here is the proper configuration:

```
application-identifier          $(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)

com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers
      Item 0                     $(TeamIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)
```

This got it to validate successfully.  I couldn't find this documented anywhere so hopefully it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution not listed that turned out to be my problem (and took me 3 days to find!).  Set your Archive Build Configuration to Release.  You can do this by going into PRODUCT -> EDIT SCHEME -> ARCHIVE -> BUILD CONFIGURATION -> SET TO RELEASE.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue having iCloud KVStore as Capability active:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
    <array/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
    <string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Xcode fails to sign to binary when I try to change the 'com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier identifier to the main app KVStore Identifier as described in

[Configuring Common Key-Value Storage for Multiple Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH6-SW26)