# iTunes Connect : why isn't my distribution profile "managed by Xcode"?

Tags: xcode, certificate, code-signing

I'm stuck with this damn "Application failed codesign verification" warning that I simply can't solve... I'm about to submit my app to Apple. :(

Having a look to my provisioning profiles made me realize that the status of my development profile is "Active, managed by Xcode" whereas my distribution profile is only "Active". It may be the reason of this problem because anything else seems to be OK. So what is wrong here ?

Thanks a lot for your advices.

Comment: Did you press the Run button or did you choose Product > Build for Archiving or Product > Archive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application failed codesign verification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474158/application-failed-codesign-verification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Having a look to my provisioning profiles made me realize that the
>   status of my development profile is "Active, managed by Xcode" whereas
>   my distribution profile is only "Active".

The team development profile includes certificates for all the developers on your team and device ID's for all your devices. Since only one person is authorized to distribute applications for any given account, and since there are no device ID's associated with the distribution provision, there's no need to have Xcode or the provisioning portal manage your distribution provision -- there'd be very little to manage.

> It may be the reason of this problem because anything else seems to be
>   OK. So what is wrong here?

No, difference in the description of your development and distribution profiles isn't the problem. The problem is that the `codesign` utility was, for some reason, unable to sign your application. There are several things that can prevent your app from being signed, such as:

- Wrong distribution profile selected in your project's build settings.
- App ID in distribution profile doesn't match that of the app you're trying to sign.
- Problem with distribution profile, e.g. an expired certificate.

There are also a [great many questions right here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxcode%5D%20%5Bios%5D%20%22application%20failed%20codesign%22) pertaining to signing your app for distribution. It doesn't make sense to rehash all those answers here, especially without more information about what you've already checked or at least seeing the specific error. Take a look at some of those questions first and see if something rings a bell. Otherwise, take a look at the [Troubleshooting section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/40-iOS_Development_Troubleshooting_Guide/ios_development_troubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH25-SW1) of the [Tools Workflow Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/00-About_the_iOS_Application_Development_Workflow/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH1-SW1).